# oracle - How do we get the smallest number value that is greater than or equal

Tags: java, oracle

How do we get the smallest number value that is greater than or equal to the argument in Oracle DB. Just like Math.ceil() method in java.

```
For eg,

0.625 -> needs to return 1
0.2 -> needs to return 1
1.2 -> needs to return 2
1.0 -> needs to return 1
```

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-sep/o52sql-1735910.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `ceil` function in Oracle!

```
select ceil(.625) from dual;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Oracle `CEIL()` function in your query. From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions017.htm)

> CEIL returns smallest integer greater than or equal to n.
>
> This function takes as an argument any numeric datatype or any nonnumeric datatype that can be implicitly  converted to a numeric datatype. The function returns the same datatype as the numeric datatype of the argument.

for instance:

```
SELECT CEIL(column) FROM table;
```